# ImportError: No module named 'PIL' ( Python 3.4.3 , (1, 8, 7, 'final', 0)

Tags: python, django, centos, amazon-ami

I am trying to run an application which I made 1 year ago and I can't seem to get it working.

I am running it under the CentOS based Amazon Linux AMI.

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 8, 7, 'final', 0)

(eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip- mysite]$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Apr  1 2015, 18:10:40)
```

Here is the error message. I get when I run **python manage.py runserver**

```
       (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ python manage.py runserver
  Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f07e8fdbbf8>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
      fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
      autoreload.raise_last_exception()
    File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
      six.reraise(*_exception)
    File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
          raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
          fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
          apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
          app_config.import_models(all_models)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
          self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/home/ec2-user/Python-3.4.3/eb_django_app/mysite/pet/models.py", line 6, in <module>
          from PIL import Image as img
      ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
      ^C(eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ python --version
      Python 3.4.3
      (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ ^C
      (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ import django
      -bash: import: command not found
      (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ python
      Python 3.4.3 (default, Apr  1 2015, 18:10:40)
      [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux
      Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
      >>> import django
      >>> django.VERSION
      (1, 8, 7, 'final', 0)
      >>>
      KeyboardInterrupt
      >>> exit()
      (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ python manage.py runserver^C
      (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ ^C
      (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ python manage.py runserver   Unhandled exception in thread started by           <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4e85362bf8>
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
          fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
          autoreload.raise_last_exception()
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
          six.reraise(*_exception)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
          raise value.with_traceback(tb)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
          fn(*args, **kwargs)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
          apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
          app_config.import_models(all_models)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
          self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
        File "/tmp/eb_django_app/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/home/ec2-user/Python-3.4.3/eb_django_app/mysite/pet/models.py", line 6, in <module>
          from PIL import Image as img
      ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

This is what happens when I try to install pip install PIL

```
   (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$  pip install PIL             Collecting PIL
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: )
    Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external PIL to allow).
  No matching distribution found for PIL
```

This is what happens when I try to install pip install Pillow

```
  (eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ pip install Pillow           Collecting Pillow
    Using cached Pillow-3.0.0.tar.gz
  Installing collected packages: Pillow
    Running setup.py install for Pillow
      Complete output from command /tmp/eb_django_app/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-      xa9ll2i4/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,       'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hlq0ym7w-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-      headers /tmp/eb_django_app/include/site/python3.4/Pillow:
      Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
            copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
      copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
running egg_info
writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-xa9ll2i4/Pillow/setup.py", line 767, in <module>
    zip_safe=not debug_build(),
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/tmp/eb_django_app/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 587, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-xa9ll2i4/Pillow/setup.py", line 515, in build_extensions
    % (f, f))
ValueError: --enable-jpeg requested but jpeg not found, aborting.

----------------------------------------
  Command "/tmp/eb_django_app/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-      xa9ll2i4/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,       'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hlq0ym7w-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-      headers /tmp/eb_django_app/include/site/python3.4/Pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xa9ll2i4/Pillow
```

python

```
 >>> from PIL import Image as img
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

UPDATED:

here the error message i received when i tried to install pillow

```
(eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ pip install pillow
Collecting pillow
  Using cached Pillow-3.0.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow
Complete output from command /tmp/eb_django_app/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-abwsqj8g/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5akg2zf0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /tmp/eb_django_app/include/site/python3.4/pillow:
Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying PIL/OleFileIO-README.md -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/PIL
running build_ext
building 'PIL._imaging' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/libImaging
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/tmp/pip-build-abwsqj8g/pillow/libImaging -I/tmp/eb_django_app/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/_imaging.o
_imaging.c:76:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/tmp/eb_django_app/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-abwsqj8g/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5akg2zf0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /tmp/eb_django_app/include/site/python3.4/pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-abwsqj8g/pillow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the libjpeg-devel package.

Under Amazon Linux AMI (that you mentioned in the coments that you're using):

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-devel
```

You might still get errors after installing this.

If you get the error:

```
ValueError: --enable-zlib requested but zlib not found, aborting.
```

install the zlib-devel package:

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

And if you get the error:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Run:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

to install gcc

If you still have a problem try installing the package:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

I switched from GCE to EC2 today (Amazon Linux AMI too) and had these errors while trying to install Pillow. After installing these packages it installed no problem.

---

the problem you're having here

```
eb_django_app)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-11-114 mysite]$ import Image as img
 -bash: import: command not found
```

is you're trying to import Image directly in the bash shell, but you must be in the python shell to import Image.

Comment: Yeah I installed Pillow and Pil and still doesn't work

Comment: @peterpan did you try using just `import Image`?

Comment: @peterpan try install `libjpeg-dev` and reinstall `Pillow`

Comment: Yeah I tried both but didn't work , have a loko at the error message i received above

Comment: @peterpan I just had (and fixed) the same problem while installing pillow on amazon linux AMI. what OS are you using?

Comment: @peterpan changed the entire answer. Try again with what I put there now. I had the same poblem as you and fixed it with the 3 commands in the answer

Comment: okay well i successfully installed the packages you mention above but i still get the same error when i try to execute runserver and when i try to import PIL in python , i can't

Comment: @peterpan you should be able to install Pillow now though. I don't know why PIL isn't working, but I'm gonna look into it

Comment: @peterpan funny, I can import PIL normally in my Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: @peterpan according to the question you're doing `import Image` directly in the bash shell. You must do it in the python code (or the python shell) for it to work. That's probably the problem

Comment: hi , i still can't but i posted the error message . Ok , Can you show me the step to import PIL from the start ? like new ami then dl

Comment: Yeah I tried to do it in python but it didn't allow me to import the module

Comment: @peterpan that should've worked in python. try `pip install image` and use `import Image` in python. If that doesnt work uninstall and install PIL

Comment: >>> import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Image'

Comment: okay , i'm going nuts , still not working and i get the same error message as before . is it because i am executing this command in virt?

Comment: @peterpan added one more package to the answer (python-devel). Try that and try installing pillow again

Comment: @peterpan virt is virtualenv? if so, there shouldnt be a problem if you're installing these packages in your virtualenv and not on the system itself

Comment: Do you have skype? Can we talk there so u might able to investigate further into the server

Comment: @peterpan can't do that. shouldn't even be here. I've got an app that i need to get up and running in a few hours. Did you install python-devel and try pillow again after that?

Comment: @peterpan but thats for image. pillow not working as well?

Comment: @dietbacon . I would like to give a big thank for assisting me!

Comment: @peterpan did it work? if not maybe try setting up a virtualenv cause idk anymore what to do haha

Comment: nope but it's driving me nuts and i think the cause is a package conflict

Comment: @peterpan i was having some probs with some python stuff so i just created a virtualenv, that was much easier. maybe try that